# Lighting not dynamically changing on objects when moved

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader, lighting

I'm having trouble with my lighting source and objects in my webGL app. In my "drawScene" function, i load the view port, clear the view, then render my light. After i identify my matrix and render my VBOs (with pushing and poping the matrix).

What happens then once i load my app, the light source is correct, its ontop of the object

I then move the light source to the left, and the lighting displays correctly on the object as it should

Then here is the problem. I move the object to the left, past the light source but the lighting on the object does not move to the right side of the object

If i were to move the lighting all the way to the left, it only changes on the object once the light passes the initial starting position (0, 0).
I thought it was a push and poping matrix issue, but i've corrected the architecture of the code. Light renders first, then the matrix is called, and then the object. It may be a issue with my shaders but i can not tell... Here is what my shaders look like. Think anyone could help me out?

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment"> // Textured, lit, normal mapped frag     shader precision mediump float;
// uniforms from app
uniform sampler2D samplerD; // diffuse texture map
uniform sampler2D samplerN; // normal texture map

uniform vec3 uLightColor;       // directional light color
uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;     // ambient light color

// interpolated values from vertex shader
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vLightDir;

void main()
{
    // get the color values from the texture and normalmap
    vec4 clrDiffuse = texture2D(samplerD, vTextureCoord);
    vec3 clrNormal = texture2D(samplerN, vTextureCoord).rgb;

    // scale & normalize the normalmap color to get a normal vector for this texel
    vec3 normal = normalize(clrNormal * 2.0 - 1.0);

    // Calc normal dot lightdir to get directional lighting value for this texel.
    // Clamp negative values to 0.
    vec3 litDirColor = uLightColor * max(dot(normal, vLightDir), 0.0);

    // add ambient light, then multiply result by diffuse tex color for final color
    vec3 finalColor = (uAmbientColor + litDirColor) * clrDiffuse.rgb;   

    // finally apply alpha of texture for the final color to render
    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor, clrDiffuse.a);
}
</script>
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> // Textured, lit, normal mapped vert     shader precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;       // Texture & normal map coords

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform vec3 uLightDir;         // Application can set desired light direction

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;         // Passed through to frag shader
varying vec3 vLightDir;         // Compute transformed light dir for frag shader

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

    vLightDir = uLightDir;
    vLightDir = normalize(vLightDir);
}
</script>
```

@MaticOblak

```
function webGLStart() { ... this.light = new Light(); ... 

function Light() { ... this.create(); ... 

Light.prototype.create = function() {
    gl.uniform3fv(shader.prog.lightDir, new Float32Array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]));
    gl.uniform3fv(shader.prog.lightColor, new Float32Array([0.8, 0.8, 0.8]));
    gl.uniform3fv(shader.prog.ambientColor, new Float32Array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2]));
}

function drawScene() { 

     ... 

     this.light.render(); 

     mat4.identity(mvMatrix); 

     mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-player.getPosition()[0], -          
     player.getPosition()[1], 0.0]); 

     mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0,   0, -20.0]);  

     this.world.render();
     this.player.render();

 Light.prototype.render= function() {

gl.uniform3f(shader.prog.lightDir,    
    this.position[0],this.position[1],this.position[2] );
}
```

Comment: That is not surprising since you are not transforming your normals when you move the object. In fact, `uLightDir` should not be something you pass to your shader. The light direction should be computed in the vertex shader from its position relative to the vertex.

Comment: You mentioned you moved the light source. Where in your code is this light source of yours?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman i forgot to mention this is only dealing with textures  and 2D objects. I am using a normal map for my sprites. Where would i be transforming my normals? I don't have a complete understanding of how normal mapping works with a 2d app, but i thought if the normals are based on a texture, there is no normals to transform since the normal map is always on the sprite.

Comment: @namenamesoseji The normals have to be in the same coordinate space as the light direction. Since translating them is meaningless, if lighting is done in view-space, then that means applying the rotation from the view matrix. I have to assume that lighting is computed in world-space and that your normal maps are also in world-space

Comment: @namenamesoseji Your biggest problem right now is that your light direction is constant. It needs to be calculated per-vertex.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman 1) http://imgur.com/oRvFu9w 2) http://imgur.com/LGIcAr9 3) http://imgur.com/StJ5JRu Is there an example you could point me to of applying the rotation in the view matrix? the lighting's position is based on 3 vars x, y, z that i can control with arrow keys

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman how would i change my shader to calculate the lighting per-vertex

Comment: @namenamesoseji Actually, nevermind. I ***just*** realized you are using a directional light and not a positional light. You cannot "move your object past the light", because the light does not have a position in the first place. Directional lights are effectively light sources ***infinitely*** far away in a certain direction, think of them almost like the sun; no matter how far you move on Earth, you will never move "past" the sun and its direction will appear fixed (ignore the fact that the Earth rotates with time and that the Earth is spherical).

Comment: Since you want a positioned light instead of a directional (sun-like) light, `u_lightDir` should instead be a `u_lightPosition` that you set appropriately in code. Then calculate `v_lightDir = normalize(u_lightPosition - position)` where `position` is the same thing you calculated for `gl_Position`. (I'm not sure if it's safe to read from `gl_Position` in WebGL.) But you will also want to add attenuation to your fragment shader, which is another issue...

Comment: Since you're doing 2D, you don't need to worry about tangent space as long as your sprites don't rotate. Axis-aligned quads have the same tangent space as local space (in terms of rotation, not position). But if you start rotating your quads, you'll need to rotate your light direction before passing it to the fragment shader.